# The content type application/xml;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I trying to consume a WCF web service using stand alone application. I am able to view this service using Internet Explorer also able to view in Visual studio service references.

This is the error I am getting

```
The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
```

How do I change this to use the correct content type?

Here is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="G2WebServiceSoap11Binding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="G2WebServiceSoap12Binding">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:XX/janus/services/G2WebService.G2WebServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="G2WebServiceSoap11Binding"
            contract="G2ServiceReference.G2WebServicePortType"
            name="G2WebServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" />
        <endpoint address="http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:XX/janus/services/G2WebService.G2WebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="G2WebServiceSoap12Binding"
            contract="G2ServiceReference.G2WebServicePortType"
            name="G2WebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

here is the stack

```
{System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type application/xml;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. 
The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /janus/services/G2WebService and the WSA Action = null&#xd;
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:89)&#xd;
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:333)&#xd;
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:264)&#xd;
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:163)&#xd;
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:136)&#xd;
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:130)&#xd;
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:829)&#xd;
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:255)&#xd;
    at com.rm.janus.webservice.GroupCallServlet.doGet(GroupCallServlet.java:33)&#xd;
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)&#xd;
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpSer'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at InetgrisG2TestApp.G2ServiceReference.G2WebServicePortType.getStudentData(getStudentDataRequest request)
   at InetgrisG2TestApp.G2ServiceReference.G2WebServicePortTypeClient.G2TestApp.G2ServiceReference.G2WebServicePortType.getStudentData(getStudentDataRequest request) in c:\Users\s\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\G2TestApp\InetgrisG2TestApp\Service References\G2ServiceReference\Reference.cs:line 2981
   at InetgrisG2TestApp.G2ServiceReference.G2WebServicePortTypeClient.getStudentData(ServiceRequest serviceReq) in c:\Users\s\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\G2TestApp\G2TestApp\Service References\G2ServiceReference\Reference.cs:line 2987
   at InetgrisG2TestApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\s\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\G2TestApp\G2TestApp\Program.cs:line 57}
```

Comment: do you get error for both the endpoints? also, please post the exception stack

Comment: Check the exception content. See if you have an `InnerException`, or something useful in the `Details` property.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263150/the-content-type-text-html-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not-match

Comment: thanks, but I need to know how to change the content type to the correct one

Comment: Seems like that the WebService is a non .NET web service and you are trying to associate it with a WCF Binding. In order to consume it just remove all web.config entries and then use the Add Service Reference option in VS.NET IDE and check if you can consume the service. I guess you would need to know the exact binding you can use against it or define a custom binding with appropriate settings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's possible that your WCF service is returning HTML.  In this case, you'll want to set up a binding on the service side to return XML instead.  However, this is unlikely: if it *is* the case, let me know and I'll make an edit with more details.

The more likely reason is that your service is throwing an error, which is returning an HTML error page.  You can take a look at [this blog post](http://noamlewis.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/custom-error-pages-and-wcf-exceptions-in-iis-and-case-of-bad-ui/) if you want details.

**tl;dr:**
There are a few possible configurations for error pages.  If you're hosting on IIS, you'll want to remove the `<httpErrors>` section from the WCF service's `web.config` file.  If not, please provide details of your service hosting scenario and I can come up with an edit to match them.

**EDIT:**

Having seen your edit, you can see the full error being returned.  Apache can't tell which service you want to call, and is throwing an error for that reason.  The service will work fine once you have the correct endpoint - you're pointed at the wrong location.  I unfortunately can't tell from the information available what the *right* location is, but either your action (currently `null`!) or the URL is incorrect.

Comment: The WEb service is a customers I don't have access to this, other than the url I am given to consume

Comment: Hi, just edited my response having seen the stack trace you put in.  Looks like you need to change your endpoint address.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The url resolves ok when I paste it into a browser. Would that eliminate the url being the problem ?

Comment: No, there's probably a mismatch between what you put in the browser and what WCF is sending.  Try using an auto-generated client proxy and see what URL it uses.

Comment: Hi, I checked with fiddler the app is sending the same url, albeit without the ?wsdl on the end. I can post the code for the project if it helps

Comment: ?wsdl is important - it means the browser is just getting "Web Services Description Language" for the service, and not calling the service.  The WSDL, if you learn to read it, will tell you the action to send.  Add that action to your client's endpoint address, and you should have more luck with the service.

Comment: Press F12 and look at the network tab in your browser. You can see the actual message returned then.

Answer (score 6):

When I ran into this error, I spent hours trying to find a solution.

My issue was that when I went to save the file I had accidentally hit the key stroke "G" in the web.config. I had a straggler Character just sittings outside, so the web.config did not know how to interpret the improperly formatted data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case...
If you are using **SoapUI Mock Service** (as the Server), calling it from a **C# WCF**:

```
WCF --> SoapUI MockService
```

And in this case you are getting the same error:

```
The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
```

Edit your Mock Response at SoapUI and add a Header to it:
[image]

In my scenario, this fix the problem.

Comment: My problem exactly.  A million thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

In WCF serive project this issue may be due to Reference of System.Web.Mvc.dll 's different version or may be any other DLL's different version issue. So this may be compatibility issue of DLL's different version

When I use

**System.Web.Mvc.dll version 5.2.2.0** -> it thorows the **Error** The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message

but when I use

**System.Web.Mvc.dll version 4.0.0.0 or lower** -> That's **works fine** in my project and not have an Error.

I don't know the reason of this different version of DLL's issue but when I  change the DLL's verison which is compatible with your WCF Project than it works fine.

**This Error even generate when you add reference of other Project in your WCF Project and this reference project has different version of System.Web.Mvc DLL or could be any other DLL.**

Comment: i m getting text/html exception only for one function where i m reducing the size of the uploaded image using WebImage.

Answer (score 1):

We use the Url Rewrite extension for IIS for redirecting all HTTP requests to HTTPS. When trying to call a service not using transport security on an http://... address, this is the error that appeared.

So it might be worth checking if you can hit both the http and https addresses of the service via a browser and that it doesn't auto forward you with a 303 status code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was simply an error in the web.config.

I had:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/WebService/WebOnlineService.asmx"
```

It should have been:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:10593/WebService/WebOnlineService.asmx"
```

The port number (:10593) was missing from the address.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an error in the web.config file.

Open up your URL in your browser, example:

```
http://localhost:61277/Email.svc
```

Check if you have a 500 Error.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
```

Look for the error in these sections:

Config Error

Config File

Answer (score 0):

Try browse the WCF in IIS see if it's alive and works normally,

In my case it's because the physical path of the WCF is misdirected.