# error with a java web service with a response type

Tags: java, .net, web-services

i am new here, the problem is that i want retrieve data from a third party web services, this web services come from another company, for the url i think that the web service was made in java ("http://javaee.ws.xxxx.com"), the problem is when i try to use a method of the web service, the method send a error and  say me that:

*"The content type text/plain of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '..."*

i try to change this

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="xxxSoapHttp" useDefaultWebProxy="True" **textEncoding="utf-8"**/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

but the error persist....

Comment: Try here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481092/the-content-type-application-xmlcharset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not

Comment: Confirm the content type being returned by your webservice. From the error returned, one can deduce that the service is not returning the expected xml format. What it is actually returning, you'll have to confirm using a tool like soapui or dumping the transport data to system.out

Comment: :), this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481092/the-content-type-application-xmlcharset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not is the solution xD