# The content type application/xml;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8), WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, encoding, utf-8

I know this question has been asked a few times before, but the solutions given either don't work for me or I'm too ignorant to fully understand how to implement the solution.

So, the website I am attempting to run runs off of a WCF client. Whenever a WCF service tries to be called (ie, any database search or edit), it comes up with this error

> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
>   If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported
>   method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response
>   were: '

When I make this error occur through an unhandled exception, this is what pops up

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDk4g.png

(Note: the line that cuts off at the end reads)

```
[ProtocolException: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Here is the web.config file used for the site (I'm not sure whether the problem is centered here, but I have a nagging suspicion it is)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DefaultConnection;Integrated Security=false;User ID=******;Password=******;"/>
    <add name="ITPDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ITPDatabase;Integrated Security=false;User ID=******;Password=******;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
    <controls>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    </controls></pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
          name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="defaultEndpointBehaviour">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
    <service name="*****.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehaviour">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="http://<domainname>.com/Service1.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>

    </service>

    </services>

    <client>
    <endpoint address="http://<domainname>.com/Service1.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    </client>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <add name="svc-Integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />  </handlers>

    </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Now, from what I gathered of other questions, the gist of the error I'm receiving is instead of getting the xml response from the database, I'm getting a html page error.

Before asking here I've been getting help from the web host's tech support, but at this point they're not sure what the problem is (or at least, the person who I was talking to was unsure)
We used IIS to attempt to tinker with certain settings in the system (to no real change) so I can safely assume the site is hosting on IIS?

Any help on the matter is greatly appeciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The content type application/xml;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481092/the-content-type-application-xmlcharset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 500 error. This means the error is being thrown on the server hosting the service and not from the caller. My guess is bad data being sent to the service, like a null or string instead of int, or not sending all the required bits the service requires.

To get a more detailed error, you will either have to

a) run the same request on the server hosting the service

eg - if your call to the service is http://www.domain.com/service.svc?id=1, have them run the URL on the server where the service is hosted and send you the error.

b) disable custom errors to get the actual error by modifying the web.config of the service

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.
I attempted to modify the web.config (and webRelease.config file as well just in case) to have the customerrors changed but the same error occurs when I attempt a search/general wcf function through the website.

However, I did try just running <domainname>/service1.svc (the same name note as the endpoint address) and I have this error page. I'm not sure, would this give any better idea on what the issue is?
http://i.imgur.com/wV8O2A6.png

Comment: Looks like IIS is missing some features. Try running this from the command line: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe

Comment: Hi, sorry for being so late on this reply, but I attempted to run the program from the command line and I got this message
http://i.imgur.com/MRKrNxF.png
I don't see any framework of 4.5 or higher on my PC at the moment, although when I try to download and install the framework it gives me this message
http://i.imgur.com/YqlIyCt.png
Is there any particular spot the 4.5 framework would be kept?
I should note that I'm also running on Windows 8

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116134/wcf-on-iis8-svc-handler-mapping-doesnt-work?rq=1