# The content type application/xml; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I'm trying to interact with a SOAP service (which I have no control over). Looking at the response, I'm assuming that the content-type on the response is application/xml.
In order to interact with this service, I'm using basicHttpBinding which sends the content-type as text/xml.
Everything is done programmatically i.e. I don't have any web.config to specify the binding information.
I've understood that BasicHttpBinding is SOAP1.1 which has the content-type as text/xml
I've also tried switching it to WSHttpBinding which is SOAP 1.2 but the only I still get the same exception since it updates the content-type to application/soap+xml.

Could someone please share their thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide the code you've tried so far and the server-side WSDL (relative to the bindings)? As the error says, this is caused by your client sending a binding which is different than what the server expects (indicated in the WSDL).

Comment: I find a similar question which may be able to help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481092/the-content-type-application-xmlcharset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not