# wcf returning only html of metadata page

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

UPDATE:  i have solved my issue:

the following config line needed removed:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

When i run the wcftestclient utility i get the following error and result from the services when invoking hello world.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I cant seem to find the issue as to why it wont invoke the specific method and return the string for hello world.

Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Comment: Have you tried setting `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to `="true"`? Because you might get better exception details.

Comment: @Silvermind i have but nothing has changed unfortunately for the error.

Comment: Perhaps there is a binding mismatch. Can you try using `basicHttpBinding` instead of `wsHttpBinding`. Update your client too. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637652/wcf-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not-match-the-content-type-of-the

Comment: @Silvermind thanks for trying to help.  after pouring over my config and looking at the msdn site i found a item in my web config that looked off so i commented it out and walla.