# response message does not match the content type exception

Tags: wcf

```
[HttpPost]
public void Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
    if (img.Width > 1000)
       img.Resize(1000, 1000);
    img.Save("path");   
}
```

Above is the code i wrote on WCF service and deployed on server. The first time when I tried to call I got http.web.helpers.dll missing error i added it in bin...2nd time i got system.web.webPages.dll missing exception again i added it .. 3rd time i got

> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). 
>       If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Runtime Error</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
                <style>
                    body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:.7em;color:black;}
                    p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
                    b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
                    H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
                    H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
                    pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
                   .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
                   .version {color: gray;}
                   .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
                   .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;color:navy; cursor:hand; }
                   @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
                   pre { width: 440px; o'.}`
```

Below is my `web.config` file details and configuration of service. Please check what I did wrong. I have even increased the timeout , message limit still getting the same issue..even locally its working fine .. no error I'm getting.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Iabcd" receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
     sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
 <endpoint address="http://abcd/abcd.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Iabcd"
    contract="abcd.Iabcd" name="BasicHttpBinding_Iabcd" />
</client>
```

Can any one please help me to fix it. I have updated my question and added the `web.config` file

Comment: Could you show us your app.config file, and how you create your bindings?

Comment: How are you consuming the service, what does the App.Config look like in your client application?

Comment: The code which i posted is the part of my web.config file... my client is MVC4 application.

Comment: Look at this answer, this is what I'm trying to get to. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8639523/5062791