# How can i resolve content type error while requesting onvif WSDL getSystemDatetime method?

Tags: xml, soap, onvif

I am trying to get datetime of IP camera using `DeviceClient` object. The same code is working in Windows form application but not in asp.net, mvc app or console app.

The content type (`text/xml; charset=utf-8`) of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (`application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8`). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xmime="http://tempuri.org/xmime.xsd" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:wsrfbf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:wstop="ht'.'
```

Comment: Perhaps you can find the answer here, check your configs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637652/wcf-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not-match-the-content-type-of-the

Comment: I think you need to look for something related to AddressingVersion...
Maybe give a look to the response i gave to my question earlier...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220574/how-to-generate-getsystemdateandtime-xml